# Chrome Extension Popup.html very slow not opens fast? 5 seconds for 1.89kb page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good day good people..

I need to ask why is that..

I made a simple chrome extension for my website. it has the following codes, but its taking around 3-5 seconds when I click on the icon why not it opens instantly?

Basically Popup.html contains an Iframe which loads a piece of webpage from google drive but its taking too much time i was wanting to publish online but who will like such slow extension?

iframe contains a google custom search box and a small form

see the code please. Help e why it is slow?

**Popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="400" height="400" name="iframe" seamless="seamless"src="https://googledrive.com/host/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.html"></iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Instant Quotes!",
    "description": "Search  Quotes Instantly!",

    "version": "0.1",
   "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Instant  Quotes!",
        "icons":
        { 
          "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon_128.png"

        },
          "app": {

    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://RationalQuotes.com/"
     }}

    }

}
```

**iframe Page**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <style>
.cse input.gsc-input, input.gsc-input {background-image:'none') !

    important;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right; }::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 10px; /* for 

    vertical scrollbars */ height: 50px; /* for horizontal scrollbars */}::-webkit-scrollbar-track{ rgba(0, 152, 199, 

    0.8);}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{ background: rgba(0, 162, 69, 0.9);}
    </style>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
(function() 

    { var cx = '009043xxxxxxxxxxx88903:ntz9xxxxxxbzw'; var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 

    'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true; gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 

    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx; document.body.appendChild(gcse); })

        ();
    </script> <span style="font-size:10px;">OR</span>

    <form>
        <span style="font-size:10px;">Book: <input id="value1" type="text"> (1
        to 200)<br>
        Page : <input id="value2" type="text"> (Depends)<br>
        <input onclick="redirect()" style="width:95px" type="button" value=
        "Meaning!"> <input onclick="Quotes()" style="width:96px" type="button"
        value="Quote!"></span>
    </form><span style="font-size:10px;"><script>
function tafsir() { window.location.assign

    ("http://www.example.com/xyz/abc/" + document.getElementById("value1").value + "/index.html");}

    </script><script>
function redirect() { window.location.assign("http://example.com/xyz/" + 

    document.getElementById("value1").value + "/" + document.getElementById("value2").value + 

    "/printview.html");}
    </script></span><span style="font-size:10px; color:#008000;">(Note: Page
    No. is Compustory for Qoutes)</span><span style="font- size:8px;"><a href=
    "http://example.blogspot.com" target=
    "_blank">RationalQoutes.com</a></span><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How long will it take if you comment out the iframe line in `popup.html` ?

Comment: Can't you just put the code of the iframe in your popup?

Answer (score -2):

Modify manifest.json

```
"background": {
"page": "popup.html"
},
```

Comment: [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) != [popup page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups)